# Running Node.js at boot

Tags: centos, node.js

I'm trying to run a node.js script at boot using `crontab`.

Here's the command

```
/usr/local/bin/forever -c /usr/local/bin/node start /var/www/html/lights.js >/var/log/lights 2>&1 &
```

At reboot, the cron log says that the command was executed, but the lights log shows this

```
/usr/bin/env: node: No such file or directory
```

Running the command works, just not when cron runs it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To start a linux deamon, server or app at boot is normally used a script in `/etc/init.d`.

Take a look at this script for starting node.js in Centos: https://gist.github.com/nariyu/1211413

After doing your own version of it with your file, you may "activate" it to run at boot with: 
`chkconfig nodejs on`
After that you may also be able to use `service nodejs start` or `service nodejs stop` to start or stop it.

Answer (score 3):

`cron` uses a very restrictive `PATH` by default.  You'll need to either have cron run a script that changes PATH, or set `PATH=` in your `crontab` file.  [See this question and answer here for details.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14694543/473915)